# How to remove extra p tags in wordpress pages or posts content

Tags: wordpress, formatting

I already added the remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); in the functions.php but still getting the extra p & br tags in the content.

Please check this page http://insideoutdogtraining.com/rescueseries

Comment: Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

use

```
echo get_the_content();
```

instead

```
the_content();
```

in your theme

Answer (score 0):

Does you post content already have these extra

and 
 tags or are they getting auto-generated when you query for them?